# Basic form security

Tags: php, forms, security

Well, I'm starting to learn PHP. So on a tutorial the author cites the `action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>"`
Well, for me, It's the same thing that a write: `action=""` and less dangerous.
**1 - Is not?**

And, easily I can note if the user add on the adress bar something like this: `%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('showing a msg on the website')%3C/script%3E` he will closes the `<form>` and will add in the source a JS alert...
But, the unique person will see this is himself
**2 - Or not?**

How can the person show this message for all visitors ?

Thank you!

Comment: Stop following that tutorial immediately and read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: security isn't only the task of `php`. use `.htaccess` to protect from url hacks.

Comment: Anyone suggest a good PHP book for me?

Answer (score 2):

Answering your first question, `action=""` is preferred over `action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"` - it's basically the same thing, and actions will default to self if not specified. That's standard practice.

Your second question, it really depends what you're doing with the query string. If you are using something like an ID or a page name, firstly you will (of course) be escaping and decoding your URL variables using functions like [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php), [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/strip_tags) etc, so you shouldn't have to worry about that.

On the off chance that somebody manages to get past your sanitizing, a script like that will only display on their screen. However, if somebody's worked out that they can get past your sub-par security, they won't just be alerting a message to their screen...

**Long and short is:**

- use a blank action to aim forms at itself
- use a header redirect once you've processed that form back to itself again to avoid the "Are you sure you wish to re-send form data?" message and/or duplicate data processing
- escape your query string variables properly so you don't have to worry about any of this

Cross Site Scripting (XSS) is a topic you should familiarize yourself with. Thankfully PHP has many inbuilt functions that help you on your way to a safe web application. Here are some links for further reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting
- http://www.veracode.com/security/xss

Comment: I know this functions... I just wanna know why the author says that the user will show that message for everyone. It wont be showed for everyone. My example is a page that has one form (name and email), so I will show what the user inputs below.

Comment: @user3125314 what tutorial are you referencing here...?

Comment: @user3125314 The author is basically stating, that if you put that code public, everyone that accesses that page will then get the offending alert.

Comment: W3cschools, but he said how to protect the form(the basic).